# Adjust Shower Mixing Valve

Tags: shower

I am trying to adjust a shower mixing value. I don't see a brand or model on it. I need to remove the handle. I see a hole on the bottom of the handle as shown in the picture. I can't find a screw or anything else to insert a screwdriver or hex key into. Any ideas how to remove it?[image]

Comment: Check in that hole with a flashlight and magnifying glass.There really should be a screw in there.

Comment: @JACK Agreed, the hole is possibly crudded up so it may be difficult to see. If there is actually no screw in there then the knob should practically fall off. If the installer tightened it hard enough to strip it then that could explain why there isn't a hex shape visible.